# What would the graph of $y=\sin(\log x)$ look like?

Tags: graphing-functions

> What would the graph of $y=\sin(\log x)$ look like?

So far I have dawn the conclusions :

1. At $x=1$ $y=0$
2. The graph never touches $x=0$ ($y$ axis)
3. The maximum is attained at $x = \exp(\pi/2)$

Comment: What is the limit you are referring to in the title?

Comment: You can look it up in WolframAlpha. [This is the link to your graph.](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dsin%28logx%29&x=0&y=0)

Comment: google: plot( '*whatever you want to plot*' )